# UTF-8 Encoding issue ( Tridion 2011 SP1)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

In one of my  project , there are pages(e.g. detail page) with vb script page template and few pages( e. g. homepage) with razor. We have £ sign in the text in the one of component’s field( named as title).

At home page £ get encoded with ?  and at detail page it is as desired, means £.

When I run this home page in template builder it looks fine (£) and in page source (at presentation server) it get encoded in ? symbol.

Now  I think that issue is somewhere at publishing. We have already set  publishing target  for encoding UTF-8 and both pages ( Home  and detail ) get published from this same publication target so how it can behave differently for these pages.

Even common master page of  this website also contains

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I Included below tag  in the web config to shoot out this issue.

```
<globalization fileEncoding="UTF-8" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

By doing this , at detail page   £ gets encoded in  some garbage characters(? symbols or rectangle boxes).

Now the points in my mind  are

-Issue  may be because of razor but the razor output is perfect in the template builder.

-Issue may be at  publishing time  but both pages get published with same publication target(UTF-8).

Could anybody  give me a right  direction to shoot out this issue.

Comment: Can you try to follow http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_4AFE6D6DFC50425D98F98B83C82E13A4 to define the property "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"? It could be that all you need to do is to set the default encoding on the JVM to UTF-8.

Comment: And don't forget the 7 checkpoints: http://elenaserghie.blogspot.nl/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Nuno for your useful comments. issue get resolved by overriding encoding at page level.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: can you post your comment as an answer so that Ram can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When having encoding issues, it is always a good idea to run through the [7 checkpoints](http://elenaserghie.blogspot.nl/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html) highlighted by Elena Serghie on her blog.